# How to share folders with samba

Tags: samba, file-sharing, shared-folders

I am sharing one ubuntu pc's folder with another ubuntu, how it is possible with samba. I have installed samba but i didn't understand how to create. 
Please help me and tell me the procedure of sharing. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 version.

Comment: Take a look at [Install and Configure Samba share in Ubuntu](http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 0):

Open "Files," navigate to the folder you want to share, right-click it, choose "Properties," switch to the "Share" tab, tick "Share this folder," adjust other options on the tab as needed and, finally, click the "Create Share" button. Its icon will now indicate (two arrows) that it is being shared.